# Styled Link Not Centred

Tags: html, css

I've styled this link using font awesome to create a down arrow to reveal/hide the login options. However, it's no-longer centre.

How can I make it centre?

I will also be making it change to an up arrow when down, to be done with javascript, if it's font awesome creating the problem please state how to fix future issues.

The site is live at http://etreecycle.co.uk for an example.

```
<!-- LOGIN / SIGNUP -->
<style>
    .e-join-container {
        position: relative;
        width: calc(90% - 20px);
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        color: #9A7D2A;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #e0dddd;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .e-join-container .e-title {
        font-size: 40px;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    .e-join-container .e-button {
        width: 200px;
        padding: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px;
        color: #9A7D2A;
        border: 5px solid #9A7D2A;
        font-weight: 800;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .e-join-container .e-button:hover {
        background-color: rgba(153,123,41,0.48);
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .e-join-container .e-show-hide {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -25px;
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
        background-color: #e0dddd;
        border-radius: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }
</style>
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
<div class="e-join-container">
    <p class="e-title">Welcome To eTree</p>
    <p>Create an account and join 1000's of shoppers seeking quality products made in our english factories.</p>
    <div class="e-join">
        <a href="/account" class="e-Login e-button">
            Login
        </a>
        <a href="/account" class="e-signup e-button">
            Signup
        </a>
    </div>
    <a class="e-show-hide"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-4x"></i></a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: centered horizontally or vertically? should it be centered as if the triangle weren't there, or should the triangle be included in the centering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
.e-join-container .e-show-hide
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #e0dddd;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: No problemo, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to remove `position: absolute; bottom: -25px;` styles for `.e-show-hide` element. With these styles, you are explicitly defining the position of the element.

Removing those styles on your website moved the element to the center.

Comment: How can I then have the link overlapping the div?

Comment: What `div` elements are you trying to overlap on each other ?